# Why the feed stories of my facebook game attempt to open the canvas instead of launch the Android/iOS mobile application?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, canvas, unity-game-engine

First at all, sorry for my bad english, I'll try to be the more specific as possible.

I have a facebook game made with Unity and using Facebook SDK for Unity, that was released to facebook canvas first. After of this, I made the mobile versions for Android and iOS, so I added at Facebook settings, enabled the "Single Sign On" and "Deep Linking" options for both platforms.

And my FB.Feed configuration on code looks like this:

```
FB.Feed("",
           "https://apps.facebook.com/epidemia-electoral",
           "Superen mi record de " + ParseUser.CurrentUser["score"].ToString() + " votos en Epidemia Electoral",
           "Epidemia Electoral de SDPnoticias desarrollado por Mixtli",
           "En Epidemia Electoral debes evitar que los enemigos de la democracia ejerzan votos malos",
           "http://static.sdpnoticias.com/epidemia-electoral/principal.jpg",
           "",
           "",
           ",
           "",
           null,
           DespuesDeCompartirCallback);
```

When someone shares their score on their Facebook wall through the game, and this publication is viewed from the native Facebook application on both Android and iOS, the link is directed to the one specified in the configuration of FB.Feed (ie, the canvas) and opens in the facebook's in-app browser, instead of launching the application.

I have understood that setting the Deep Linking as you can see above, should suffice for Facebook to launch the application.

I understand that this error occurs in the native facebook application on iOS, as the game is not yet in the AppStore, but still in the Android happens and my game is available in Play Store.

I appreciate the help you can give me, I'm really stuck with this and do not know what to do.

**Edit**

When the Feed request is being sent (from my app), the Android log show this:

```
I/Unity   ( 3300): Aqui deberia desabilitar el maldito locker
I/Unity   ( 3300):  
I/Unity   ( 3300): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity   ( 3300): 
I/Unity   ( 3300): Se apreto el boton
I/Unity   ( 3300):  
I/Unity   ( 3300): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity   ( 3300): 
I/Unity   ( 3300): Entro aqui porque ya se habian aceptado los permisos
I/Unity   ( 3300):  
I/Unity   ( 3300): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity   ( 3300): 
V/FBUnitySDK( 3300): FeedRequest({"callback_id":"2","link":"https://apps.facebook.com/epidemia-electoral","name":"Superen mi record de 84 votos en Epidemia Electoral","caption":"Epidemia Electoral de SDPnoticias desarrollado por Mixtli","description":"En Epidemia Electoral debes evitar que los enemigos de la democracia ejerzan votos malos","picture":"http://static.sdpnoticias.com/epidemia-electoral/principal.jpg"})
I/ActivityManager(  744): START u0 {cmp=com.sdpnoticias.epidemiaelectoral/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10179 on display 0
V/WindowManager(  744): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{13a6797d token=Token{100053d4 ActivityRecord{5c05527 u0 com.sdpnoticias.epidemiaelectoral/com.facebook.unity FBUnityDialogsActivity t21324}}} to stack=1 task=21324 at 1
I/Unity   ( 3300): Aqui deberia desabilitar el maldito locker
I/Unity   ( 3300):  
I/Unity   ( 3300): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity   ( 3300): 
I/ActivityManager(  744): START u0 {act=com.facebook.platform.PLATFORM_ACTIVITY cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] pkg=com.facebook.katana cmp=com.facebook katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformActivity (has extras)} from uid 10179 on display 0
W/ResourcesManager(  744): Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
V/WindowManager(  744): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{1ef8d940 token=Token{23531cc3 ActivityRecord{a940072 u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common activity.PlatformActivity t21324}}} to stack=1 task=21324 at 2
V/WindowManager(  744): Adding window Window{351db1be u0 com.sdpnoticias.epidemiaelectoral/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity} at 12 of 18 (after Window{30144680 u0 com.sdpnoticias.epidemiaelectoral/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity})
I/ActivityManager(  744): START u0 {cmp=com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity (has extras)} from uid 10077 on display 0
V/WindowManager(  744): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{d505b35 token=Token{3032496c ActivityRecord{20c0c21f u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common activity.PlatformWrapperActivity t21324}}} to stack=1 task=21324 at 3
V/WindowManager(  744): Adding window Window{239613b u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformActivity} at 13 of 19 (after Window{351db1be u0 com.sdpnoticias.epidemiaelectoral/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity})
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/ActivityManager(  744): START u0 {cmp=com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.composer.activity.ComposerActivity (has extras)} from uid 10077 on display 0
V/WindowManager(  744): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{7ca5a04 token=Token{14d2d617 ActivityRecord{16cc3a96 u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.composer.activity ComposerActivity t21324}}} to stack=1 task=21324 at 4
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
V/WindowManager(  744): Adding window Window{cc10f2b u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.composer.activity.ComposerActivity} at 14 of 20 (after Window{239613b u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformActivity})
W/IdleConnectionHandler(26354): Removing a connection that never existed!
W/IdleConnectionHandler(26354): Removing a connection that never existed!
W/IdleConnectionHandler(26354): Removing a connection that never existed!
W/IdleConnectionHandler(26354): Removing a connection that never existed!
W/IdleConnectionHandler(26354): Removing a connection that never existed!
W/IdleConnectionHandler(26354): Removing a connection that never existed!
W/IdleConnectionHandler(26354): Removing a connection that never existed!
W/IdleConnectionHandler(26354): Removing a connection that never existed!
W/IdleConnectionHandler(26354): Removing a connection that never existed!
W/IdleConnectionHandler(26354): Removing a connection that never existed!
W/IdleConnectionHandler(26354): Removing a connection that never existed!
W/IdleConnectionHandler(26354): Removing a connection that never existed!
I/LatinIME:LogUtils( 1218): Dictionary info: dictionary = spellcheck_userunigram.es ; version = 1429753398 ; date = 1429753398
I/LatinIME:LogUtils( 1218): Dictionary info: dictionary = spellcheck_contacts.es ; version = 1431200817 ; date = 1431200818
I/ActivityManager(  744): Displayed com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.composer.activity.ComposerActivity: +820ms (total +1s185ms)
I/LatinIME:LogUtils( 1218): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:es ; version = 49 ; date = 1404131680
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/LatinIME:LogUtils( 1218): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:es ; version = 49 ; date = 1404131680
W/SubtypeSwitcher( 1218): Cant find emoji subtype
W/SubtypeSwitcher( 1218): No input method subtype found; returning dummy subtype: Multi-lingual subtype: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodSubtype@d78b2ed0, [zz]
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ViewPager( 1218): Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1
I/LatinIME( 1218): Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
I/LatinIME:LogUtils( 1218): Dictionary info: dictionary = ContextualDictionary.es_US ; version = 1431355765 ; date = ?
E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper( 1218): Failed to get contextual suggestions.
E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper( 1218): package name: com.facebook.katana
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
D/audio_hw_primary(  190): disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
D/audio_hw_primary(  190): disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/art     (26354): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 106281(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 14(229KB) LOS objects, 3% free, 103MB/108MB, paused 3.466ms total 111.812ms
I/ThermalEngine(  200): TM Id 'battery_LCD_monitor' Sensor 'batt_therm' - alarm raised 4 at 360.0 degC
E/ThermalEngine(  200): override action 2500
E/ThermalEngine(  200): Thermal-Server: Thermal received msg override 2500
E/ThermalEngine(  200): override_notify : SS mode 1 override 2500
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
D/UsageMeterService( 4742): --> Time left before next sync : 0 day(s), 7h 4m 7s
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/art     (  744): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 40967(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(32KB) LOS objects, 27% free, 42MB/58MB, paused 2.386ms total 126.420ms
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
V/WindowManager(  744): Adding window Window{9eec4f5 u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity} at 14 of 21 (before Window{cc10f2b u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.composer.activity.ComposerActivity})
V/WindowManager(  744): Adding window Window{165040fb u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity} at 14 of 22 (before Window{9eec4f5 u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity})
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/ActivityManager(  744): Start proc 6201:com.android.providers.calendar/u0a1 for content provider com.android.providers.calendar/.CalendarProvider2
W/ResourcesManager( 6201): Asset path '/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
I/CalendarProvider2( 6201): Created com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarAlarmManager@27b053e(com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2@15ee4f9f)
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/CalendarProvider2( 6201): Sending notification intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED dat=content://com.android.calendar }
W/ContentResolver( 6201): Failed to get type for: content://com.android.calendar (Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar)
I/ActivityManager(  744): Start proc 6223:com.google.android.calendar/u0a28 for broadcast com.google.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.alerts.AlertReceiver
D/UsageMeterService( 4742): --> Time left before next sync : 0 day(s), 7h 4m 2s
E/SQLiteLog( 6223): (283) recovered 84 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.google.android.calendar/databases/timelydata.db-wal
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/AnalyticsLogBase( 6223): PlayLogger.onLoggerConnected
I/AnalyticsLogBase( 6223): PlayLogger.onLoggerConnected
V/FBUnitySDK( 3300): sending to Unity OnFeedRequestComplete({"id":"1310401304_10204013863569487","callback_id":"2"})
D/audio_hw_primary(  190): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
D/audio_hw_primary(  190): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
D/msm8974_platform(  190): platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
D/audio_hw_primary(  190): enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
D/audio_hw_primary(  190): enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
E/BufferQueueProducer(  176): [SurfaceView] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
I/Unity   ( 3300): Aqui deberia desabilitar el maldito locker
I/Unity   ( 3300):  
I/Unity   ( 3300): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity   ( 3300): 
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/Unity   ( 3300): Supuestamente se compartio todo bien =)
I/Unity   ( 3300):  
I/Unity   ( 3300): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity   ( 3300): 
I/Unity   ( 3300): Se activa el Fade Out
I/Unity   ( 3300):  
I/Unity   ( 3300): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity   ( 3300): 
I/Unity   ( 3300): Esta haciendo el fadeout
I/Unity   ( 3300):  
I/Unity   ( 3300): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity   ( 3300): 
I/Unity   ( 3300): Aqui deberia desabilitar el maldito locker
I/Unity   ( 3300):  
I/Unity   ( 3300): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity   ( 3300): 
I/Unity   ( 3300): Esta haciendo el fadeout
```

When the feed story is selected (from native facebook app on Android), the Android log show this:

```
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
D/WifiService(  744): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@135b36c5}
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
D/WifiService(  744): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@135b36c5}
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/ActivityManager(  744): START u0 {cmp=com.sdpnoticias.epidemiaelectoral/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10179 on display 0
V/WindowManager(  744): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{13a6797d token=Token{100053d4 ActivityRecord{5c05527 u0 com.sdpnoticias.epidemiaelectoral/com.facebook.unity FBUnityDialogsActivity t21324}}} to stack=1 task=21324 at 1
I/ActivityManager(  744): START u0 {act=com.facebook.platform.PLATFORM_ACTIVITY cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] pkg=com.facebook.katana cmp=com.facebook katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformActivity (has extras)} from uid 10179 on display 0
W/ResourcesManager(  744): Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
V/WindowManager(  744): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{1ef8d940 token=Token{23531cc3 ActivityRecord{a940072 u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common activity.PlatformActivity t21324}}} to stack=1 task=21324 at 2
V/WindowManager(  744): Adding window Window{351db1be u0 com.sdpnoticias.epidemiaelectoral/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity} at 12 of 18 (after Window{30144680 u0 com.sdpnoticias.epidemiaelectoral/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity})
I/ActivityManager(  744): START u0 {cmp=com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity (has extras)} from uid 10077 on display 0
V/WindowManager(  744): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{d505b35 token=Token{3032496c ActivityRecord{20c0c21f u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common activity.PlatformWrapperActivity t21324}}} to stack=1 task=21324 at 3
V/WindowManager(  744): Adding window Window{239613b u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformActivity} at 13 of 19 (after Window{351db1be u0 com.sdpnoticias.epidemiaelectoral/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity})
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/ActivityManager(  744): START u0 {cmp=com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.composer.activity.ComposerActivity (has extras)} from uid 10077 on display 0
V/WindowManager(  744): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{7ca5a04 token=Token{14d2d617 ActivityRecord{16cc3a96 u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.composer.activity ComposerActivity t21324}}} to stack=1 task=21324 at 4
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
V/WindowManager(  744): Adding window Window{cc10f2b u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.composer.activity.ComposerActivity} at 14 of 20 (after Window{239613b u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformActivity})
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
V/WindowManager(  744): Adding window Window{9eec4f5 u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity} at 14 of 21 (before Window{cc10f2b u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.composer.activity.ComposerActivity})
V/WindowManager(  744): Adding window Window{165040fb u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity} at 14 of 22 (before Window{9eec4f5 u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity})
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/ActivityManager(  744): Start proc 6201:com.android.providers.calendar/u0a1 for content provider com.android.providers.calendar/.CalendarProvider2
W/ResourcesManager( 6201): Asset path '/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/ActivityManager(  744): Start proc 6223:com.google.android.calendar/u0a28 for broadcast com.google.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.alerts.AlertReceiver
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
W/ActivityManager(  744): getTasks: caller 10113 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output
```

Then it happens what had already commented: try to open the facebook canvas on the in-app browser, instead of launching the application.

**Edit**

A behavior I noticed is that when someone shared their record and haven't installed the native facebook app, the feed history shared work correctly.

Comment: Are you signed into the Facebook application? Is something that looks related happening in android log when you initiate this action?

Comment: @MaxYankov I just added the android log outputs in the question details. Hope you can help me see if there's something strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ricardo, I recommend you read the [App Links docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks). This is the recommended way to achieve what you want.

If you implement App Links, what will happen will be the following:

- If someone who doesn't have your app installed, they will be redirected to Google Play or the Apple App Store, assuming you configured these in your URL.
- If someone who has your app installed, they will be redirected to your App, assuming you configured your native clients to support incoming App Links.
- If they click the story on an unsupported platform, you can choose a fallback URL to redirect them to (your canvas app?)

The setting that got you confused (`Deep Linking`) doesn't imply Facebook will figure how to open your app for you, but you're rather letting them know that links posted will open your app at some point.

Comment: Thank you @convuszero, it was just what I did and I solved much of the problem, except that instead of opening my Android application always asks me if I want to install, even if it is already installed on the device.